# react native require() pass local image from json data. Invalid call at line 9: require("./../assets/data/item/" + image)

Tags: react-native, image

i basically wanna do is to call a local image which path is stored in json.

**My Json:**

```
"gallery": [
  {
   "id": 1,
   "image": "dog1.jpg"
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "image": "dog2.jpg"
  }
]
```

**My Component:**

```
const Thumbnail = (props) => {
    const image = props.image
    return (
        <View>
            <Image source={require(`../assets/data/item/${image}`)} style={styles.image} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

this codes throw following error

```
TransformError components\Thumbnail.js: components\Thumbnail.js:Invalid call at line 9: require("../assets/data/item/" + image)
```

i tried hardcoding the image value like this

```
const Thumbnail = (props) => {
    const image = "dog1.jpg"
    return (
        <View>
            <Image source={require(`../assets/data/item/${image}`)} style={styles.image} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

it works. but i want the value to be dynamic from json.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the good practice, you can do the following

```
"gallery": [
  {
   "id": 1,
   "image": require(`../assets/data/item/dog1.jpg`) // this way
  },
  ....
]

const Thumbnail = (props) => {
    .....
      <Image source={image} style={styles.image} />
    ....
}
```

You can find details [Here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#static-image-resources)

Comment: i tried this. i get this error.

Error: Unknown named module: "../assets/data/item/dog1.jpg"

image path is correct